# Как показывать товары которых нет в наличии Wocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Требуется выводить в каталог товары, которых нет в наличии, нашел исходник кода, попробовал внедрить его, но ничего не поменялось. Кто-то сталкивался с этим? Плагины не могу подходящие найти.

Comment: `Плагины не могу подходящие найти.` -- просто это из коробки доступно. `WooCommerce -> Settings -> Products -> Inventory and add a checkmark to “Out of stock product visibility.”`